# How to <select> only none existing users from a case. SQL SELECT

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Working on selecting all users into an html `<select>` that doesn't exist in it already.

I am working on a "case" website where I can put users on cases. Users can be put on multiple cases at once. I am making a html `<select>` with all the users I can add to the case and it is important that already existing users on that case aren't shown.

I have 3 SQL tables. `Users`, `Cases`, and `Junc_jobs`. Junc_`J`obs works as a many to many relations to connect users and cases. All the users that I want to select are `fk_role > 1`.

```
USERS
+-------+------------+----------+
|  id   | firstName  | fk_case  |
+-------+------------+----------+
|  05   | Rasmus     | 57       |
|  06   | Ulrik      | 57       |
|  10   | Nick       | 59       |
|  12   | Lisa       | 59       |
|  22   | Marco      | 65       |
|  23   | Frederik   | 63       |
+-------+------------+----------+

CASES
+-------+------------+
|  id   | caseName   | 
+-------+------------+
|  57   | case 1     | 
|  59   | case 2     | 
|  63   | case 3     | 
|  64   | case 4     |
|  65   | case 5     | 
+-------+------------+

JUNC_JOBS
+-------+------------+--------------+
|  id   | fk_case    | fk_employee  |
+-------+------------+--------------+
|  1    | 57         | 5            |
|  2    | 59         | 5            |
|  3    | 64         | 23           |
|  4    | 65         | 23           |
|  5    | 65         | 22           |
|  6    | 66         | 10           |
|  7    | 61         | 22           |
|  8    | 60         | 5            |
|  9    | 63         | 5            |
|  10   | 66         | 22           |
|  11   | 62         | 12           |
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

So far I've tried doing something like this:

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName, junc_jobs.fk_case FROM users
LEFT JOIN junc_jobs ON users.id = junc_jobs.fk_employee
WHERE (fk_case IS NULL AND users.fk_role > 1) OR (fk_case != 66 AND  users.fk_role > 1)
ORDER BY firstName
```

BUT if `junc_jobs` contain users with multiple cases it stops working. We get something like this:

```
+-------+------------+----------+
|  id   | firstName  | fk_case  |
+-------+------------+----------+
|  06   | Ulrik      | 57       |
|  05   | Rasmus     | 57       |
|  12   | Lisa       | 59       |
|  10   | Nick       | 59       |
|  05   | Rasmus     | 59       |
|  23   | Frederik   | 63       |
|  06   | Macro      | 63       |
|  23   | Frederik   | 64       |
|  23   | Frederik   | 65       |
|  22   | Marco      | 65       |
|  10   | Nick       | 65       |
+-------+------------+----------+
```

As you can see, users that are on `fk_case = 66` is removed, but if that user is already on other cases they still get shown. User with `id = 22` is on `fk_case 66` and this user removed from the list completely.

I tried using `GROUP BY ID` to only show one of each users, but the users that are already on the case and have other cases, is shown too.

Comment: Your WHERE condition can be simplify to `(fk_case IS NULL OR fk_case != 66) AND  users.fk_role > 1`

Comment: You include the current output but what would be your desire output? Because if you are looking for users for case 66, then fk_case should be irrelevant for the SELECT combo

Comment: Why does the `users` table have a `fk_case` column? Isn't that what the `junc_jobs` table is for? And where is the `fk_role` column in `users`?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe is the current one or first case? Anyway shouldnt be there anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `fk_case` test in the `ON` clause, and then only show the users with no match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName
FROM users as U
LEFT JOIN junc_jobs AS j ON u.id = j.fk_employee AND j.fk_case = 66
WHERE j.fk_case IS NULL AND u.fk_role > 1
```

Comment: This seems to work. I just added fk_role > to the WHERE. I wasn't aware it was possible to add AND on a LEFT JOIN. Thank you so much for the help ^^

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need `fk_case` for the SELECT, because if user is on other projects doesn't matter. Only matter he isn't on the current one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName
FROM users
LEFT JOIN junc_jobs ON users.id = junc_jobs.fk_employee
WHERE users.fk_role > 1
  AND (fk_case IS NULL OR fk_case != 66)
ORDER BY firstName
```

Also not sure about what junc_jobs does, but maybe something like this may help

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.fk_role > 1
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM junc_jobs j 
                   WHERE j.fk_employee = u.id and j.fk_case = 66)
```